# Facebook Graph API - Error on success?

Tags: facebook, google-chrome, facebook-javascript-sdk, photo-upload

I am using the Facebook Javascript SDK to upload a photo to the user's timeline. This is my call:

```
function post_photo_to_facebook() {
    var file_name = 'https://my-image.url.com/image.jpg';
    var access_token = FB.getAuthResponse()['accessToken'];
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos",
        data: {
            message: "Here is my message",
            url: file_name,
            access_token: access_token,
            format: "json"
        },
        success: function(data){
            alert("POST SUCCESSFUL");
        },
        error: function(data){
            alert('Error');
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}
```

When in Chrome, I am receiving an Error back from this AJAX call, yet the statusText is "OK", and the image is being successfully uploaded to my timeline. I am just wondering what I am missing here - why is the error being called?

Comment: Instead of your error function above, if you do the following:       `error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert("Error:" + xhr.status);
        alert(thrownError);  
      }`  what error is displayed?

Comment: thrownError = "SyntaxError: Unexpected token :"
 and xhr.status = 200

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using [FB.api](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api/) to upload images, rather than ajax POST due to CORS reasons.

So your code above would look like this:

```
var file_name = 'https://my-image.url.com/image.jpg';

FB.api('/me/photos', 'post', {
    message:'Here is my message',
    url:file_name        
}, function(response){

    if (!response || response.error) {
        alert('Error occured');
    } else {
        alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
    }

});
```

and you use `FB.init` to set up your tokens etc.

Comment: I tried using the FB api, and it does not work either. It will not even post the photo. I'll update my question to hold the API call I'm using

Comment: Nevermind man. It seems that my .api call was not working simply because I was defining the data as an array and not an object.. Thanks for making me look at it again!